# Kernel size is different in keras from what I have specified

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been working with the convolutional neural network with Keras. I used the below image and converted it into an array.

[image]

```
img_arr = np.array(img)
img_arr = img_arr/255.0

>>>
array([[[0.03137255, 0.0627451 , 0.1372549 ],
        [0.01960784, 0.05098039, 0.1254902 ],
        [0.03921569, 0.07058824, 0.15294118],
        ...,
        [0.01960784, 0.08627451, 0.04705882],
        [0.01568627, 0.06666667, 0.02745098],
        [0.        , 0.05098039, 0.01176471]],

       [[0.35686275, 0.38431373, 0.45490196],
        [0.32941176, 0.35686275, 0.42745098],
        [0.31372549, 0.34117647, 0.41568627],
        ...,

img_arr = np.expand_dims(img_arr, 0)
print(img_arr.shape)

>>> (1, 343, 499, 3)
```

This is how I preprocessed the image and created an Array out of it. Then I ran `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` on this array like this,

```
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3))
output_conv1 = conv1(img_arr)
print(output_conv1.shape)

>>> TensorShape([1, 341, 497, 32])
```

The output shape is completely understandable. But the problem is when I print the `kernel` shape in Keras,

```
print(conv1.kernel.shape)

>>> TensorShape([3, 3, 3, 32])
```

I passed kernel_size as `(3, 3)` then why there are '3' `(3, 3, 3)` in the kernel shape? The last axis is `32` I think it is because of `no. of filters`. But the first 3 axis which is `(3, 3, 3)` is the thing which I am not understanding!

Comment: What you are providing is the spatial height and widht of the kernel as `(3, 3)`. The convolutional kernel also needs a depth size which it infers from the input. Here the input channel size is 3 which is what the kernel depth size is.

Comment: @AritraRoyGosthipaty, I understood, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the last `3` is referring to the number of channels. You are applying a `3x3` kernel to 3 channels. If you check out the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.6.0/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L194), you will quickly understand how the `kernel_shape` is built:

```py
kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (input_channel // self.groups, self.filters)
```